# How can I build an infinitely recursive listview control?

Tags: asp.net, listview, user-controls, recursion

Not sure I'm asking the right question, but it's a start. I have a user control with a ListView and, ideally, I would like to nest this same control inside of the ListView to provide recursion. This would behave somewhat like a TreeView with child nodes.

This might be a monumentally bad idea. :) In fact, I feed like MSFT is pointing me in that direction, because when I try this I am told that I can't do it.

So, how would you do this? What's the right way?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why an infinitely recursive listview control would be better (in your instance) than a TreeView.

Comment: I assume you're using the ListView in report mode? Are you trying to achieve something like a nested grid/data view? Something like this http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx#hierarchy-(master-detail-layout)-with-tabbed-child-view ?

Comment: @Andrew: The TreeView doesn't have enough features and won't auto-postback OnCheckChanged. I've gone round and round with TreeView and have landed in this spot of trying to create a control that behaves exactly the way I tell it to. :)

Comment: @Jason: I have to admit, I haven't encountered a "Report Mode" in the ListView control. I can tell you that I haven't specified any "modes" on my ListView if that helps. What I'm trying to achieve is something more like a TreeView, but nesting the same control to cause recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like You do need a TreeView after all, but need more functionality than it provides by default... How about extending the TreeNode/TreeView?

Here is an example for that:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/DropDownTreeView.aspx

Or you can extend the ListView, in fact, this article shows how to create a TreeListView which sounds very similar to what you're trying to do:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/extendedlistviews.aspx

Either way, it sounds like you need a custom control, based on the TreeView and ListView.

Good Luck!

Comment: I've seen those articles before, but I didn't give them enough attention as I was researching. Probably moving too fast. On your recommendation, I'll give them a good read and see what I come up with.

Comment: Neither of those articles are for asp.net... the search goes on!

Comment: Indeed. It would be nice to know more details about what exactly you're trying to do.

This seems to have the post back on checkbox checks:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ASTreeView.aspx

This shows how to force a postback:
http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx

Finally, this shows how to build a custom control from scratch:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/ASPNETCookbook.aspx